# Shell script to pass the output of first command to the next in pipe

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I would like to grep exception or error from logs, but the problem is that the exact log file name is unknown. One thing for sure is that the latest file is my log file and i want to do this single command since, i'll be using the command to do ssh from single source to multiple servers

like

```
ssh user@server "ls -ltr console*.log | tail -1; egrep -i 'exception|error' <<output of first command (i.e) log file name>>"
```

is this possible to do in single command ??

Comment: `tail -1; egrep` -> `tail -1 | xargs epgrep`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, i finally got it worked

ssh user@server "ls -ltr console*.log | tail -1; awk '{print $9}' | xargs egrep -i 'exception|error' <<output of first command (i.e) log file name>>"

Comment: you do NOT need `awk '{print $9}'` if yo just remove the `-l` from `ls` command..

Comment: Also, the `;` right before `awk` is inaccurate, has to be a `|` ... very bad and non-working solution

Comment: @Ron, ya sorry typo, below is the right one





`ssh user@server "ls -ltr console*.log | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}' | xargs egrep -i 'exception|error'`

Comment: Once again. You will not need the awk if you remove the `l` option from `ls` ... what you are still doing shows how you do not want to understand or improve your code... and this answer is unacceptable

Comment: @Ron, ya both the command works fine.. i think awk can be removed for readability. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
egrep -i 'exception|error' < $(\ls -tr console*.log|tail -1)
```

- to get only the log name do not use `-l` in `ls`

Comment: Thanks Ron, it works too. i finally got it worked with the below command.

ssh user@server "ls -ltr console*.log | tail -1; awk '{print $9}' | xargs egrep -i 'exception|error' <<output of first command (i.e) log file name>>"

Comment: That command of yours will not work, and is very poor overall..